# How can I check if apache2 service is running with a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I want to monitor apache service for ubuntu but below script is not working.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $(ps aux | grep apache2 | wc -l) -gt 1 ]; then
  echo "Statistic:0"
else
  echo "Statistic:1"
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: _"is not working"_ is not a problem description. Describe what you expect to happen, and also what actually happens. Take the [tour] you were offered when you posted, and see [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: What do you mean by _monitor apaci_? What are the curly braces doing in your script? How is the script going to be invoked?

Answer (score 0):

I edited your question to make it readable - but I think it is working as expected once the format is cleaned up. It looks like you are trying to find out if apache2 is running.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [ $(ps aux | grep apache2 | wc -l) -gt 1 ]; then
  echo "Statistic:0"
else
  echo "Statistic:1"
fi

exit 0
```

Depending on what "flavor" of linux you are running, the following might be a better option for you. You can also use `is-enabled`, `is-failed`, to check other status.

```bash
if systemctl is-active -q apache2; then
  echo "Statistic:0"
else
  echo "Statistic:1"
fi
```